# How to upload file from web(remote server)

Tags: java, selenium

How to upload file from remote place( e.g http://localhost:4444/../file.txt) using Selenium webdriver in Java?

I tried with sendKeys() method but

WebElement fileInput.sendKeys(..);

sendKeys accept only char sequence or Absolute path.

please share some idea or scripts for uploading file placed at remote place.

Comment: This looks like an offtopic question: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Comment: First set the file detector with `driver.setFileDetector`, then use `element.sendKeys("full file path")` on the `input` element to upload the file.